# Use another bean as parameter for constructor injection

Tags: spring

I there any posibility to inject bean member into constructor of another bean member? Something like code below:

```
class Config {
    @Resource("${root-service}")
    IServiceRoot root;

    @Resource("${child-service}")
    IServiceChild child;
}

@Component("root1")
class ServiceRoot1 implements IServiceRoot {
}

@Component("root2")
class ServiceRoot2 implements IServiceRoot {
}


@Component("child1")
class ServiceChild1 implements IServiceChild {
    public ServiceChild1(IServiceRoot r) {
        root = r;
    }
}

@Component("child2")
class ServiceChild2 implements IServiceChild {
    public ServiceChild2(IServiceRoot r) {
        root = r;
    }
}
```

`child-service` and `root-service` props are set to "child1/child2" and "root1/root2" respectively. Now I want to be able to construct child member using root member.

```
@Resource(${child-service})
@ConstructorArg(member="root")
ServiceChild child;
```

So after constructing root by spring it will be used to construct child. How can I achieve behaviour like `@ConstructorArg`?

Comment: Are you referring to [constructor injection](http://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring)?

Comment: @Morfic yes I want to use constructor injectinons, but I have more than one implementation of IChildService and more than one of IRootService, so I want to pass root member after it's construction(implementation is based on runtime parameter ${root-service} to constructor of child member(which implementation is also based.on parameter)

Comment: If you have multiple beans of the same time, you can use [`@Qualifier("root1")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) on the constructor argument or change the arguments names from `r` so they match the beans (eg `root1` & `root2`), to inject the specific bean instance. Am I missing something? If yes, please consider updating the question with a [sscce](http://sscce.org) which shows what you've tried so far and reproduces your actual issue.